# SQL obtain all rows where rows with this id hasn't value 'a'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

I have a table with fields 'id', 'data', 'var' where id can be repeated. For example:

```
id  data   var 
 1  data1  a   
 1  data2  b   
 2  data3  a   
 3  data4  b   
 4  data5  a
```

I want get all rows, where 'var'='b' and row with the same 'id' is unique. In this example i want obtain only row with data4 and not data1 and data2 because row with data1 has 'var'='a'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not in` as follows:

```sql
select *
from table
where var = 'b'
and id not in (select id from table where var <> 'b')
```

I'm selecting in subquery all ids where it's not equals 'b', and then I'm checking the id should not equal the return id.

As you can see here:

> ```
> create table test(
>   id int,
>   data varchar(10),
>   var varchar(10)
> );
> insert into test(id,data,var)
> values 
> (1,  'data1',  'a'),   
> (1,  'data2',  'b'),   
> (2,  'data3',  'a'),   
> (3,  'data4',  'b'),   
> (4,  'data5',  'a'),
> (5,  'data5',  'b'),
> (5,  'data5',  'c');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from test
> where var = 'b'
> and id not in (select id from test where var <> 'b')
> ```
>
> ```
> id | data  | var
> -: | :---- | :--
>  3 | data4 | b
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=13cc138c63dd2311db392e7487b54b78)*